# Using arsenal function tableby to create multiple columns and adding specific numeric stat to one row

Tags: r

I'd like to point out, that this is my second week into coding so it's all new to me.

I've tried to search for answers to my questions, but have failed so far, so I thought I'd try and ask on here. I have two questions:

First, I've successfully created a table using arsenal's tableby function - so far so good. Using "countpct" as my numeric stats, so I have my overall numbers and percentages, my string:

```
Table1 <- tableby( ~ sex + agehilo + HiloDOW + URV.Y.N + URV.days + triagefactorsum + chronicdisease + death , data = all_data1, control = mycontrols)
```

I would now like to include two more columns in my Table1, so I have three total. One with "overall" and one with URV.Y.N = 1 and one with URV.Y.N = 0. (URV.Y.N is either 1 or 0)

I have tried:

```
Table1 <- tableby(URV.Y.N ~ sex + agehilo + HiloDOW + URV.Y.N + URV.days + triagefactorsum + chronicdisease + death , data = all_data1, control = mycontrols)
```

Which gets me my two extra columns, in the correct manner, so now I'm now to "fuse" the two - so I get one table, with three columns:

```
Table1 <- tableby(overall + URV.Y.N ~ sex + agehilo + HiloDOW + URV.Y.N + URV.days + triagefactorsum + chronicdisease + death , data = all_data1, control = mycontrols)
```

This is not working - I've tried a myriad of other things as well, so I'm hoping someone has a way to get all three colums into one table.

My second question is simpler, but equally frustrating: How do I get URV.days to show up only as the median?

I've tried:

```
Table1 <- tableby( ~ sex + agehilo + HiloDOW + URV.Y.N + URV.days(numeric.stats=c("median")) + triagefactorsum + chronicdisease + death , data = all_data1, control = mycontrols)
```

and

```
Table1 <- tableby( ~ sex + agehilo + HiloDOW + URV.Y.N + URV.days("median") + triagefactorsum + chronicdisease + death , data = all_data1, control = mycontrols)
```

In both cases, I get: "Error in URV.days: Could not fund function "URV.days".

The line of codes words fine if I don't put anything after "URV.days" - I just don't get the output I'm looking for.

Comment: You should read the [ask] page more thoroughly. Multiple questions are deprecated. Also it would be more courteous to include a line like: `library(arsenal)` and it would be even more courteous to include sufficient data using a method perhaps along the lines of `dput(head(all_data1))` and `dput(mycontrols)` (assuming the code can run with six lines of data.) If the `tableby` function needs more data than that, then simplify the formula until the function can have a chance. For you second question you might want to reverse URV.days("median") to be `median(URV.days)`.

Comment: I apologize, I certainly didn't mean to be rude. I will stick to one questions next time, and try to be more clear. I cant include the dput(head(all_data1) unfortunately, there is sensitive info in it. I appreciate the feedback, and will stick to one question: Reversing to median(URV.days) unfortunately didn't work, i got error in model.frame.defualt [...]: variable lengths differ. Any other ideas as to how I could make it work?  tried it with numeric.stats = c(median("URV.days")) as well - got error: unexpected "=".

Comment: Hello and welcome to R language and R stats! I was struggling with a similar issue and this post helped me a lot: https://thatdatatho.com/2018/08/20/easily-create-descriptive-summary-statistic-tables-r-studio/